# How to apply different validations (max char) on different textFields

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two textfields one is Zip and another is Phone number. I want the validation that zip textfield only contain 6 digits of number and phone number textfield only contain 10 digits of number. I am Using the below code . I have difficulity is that i am not able to validate both textfield at same time.`enter code here`

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if(textField.tag != 10 && textField.tag !=11)

    if(string.length == 0)
        return YES;

    if (zipTxt.text.length == 6)
        return NO;

    if(phoneTxt.text.length == 10)
        return NO;

    NSCharacterSet *nonNumberSet = [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet];

    if ([string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:nonNumberSet].location != NSNotFound)
    {
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}


-(BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField.tag == 10)
    {
        if (zipTxt.text.length<6)
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Please enter a valid zip number" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
        }
    }
    if (textField.tag ==11)
    {

         if(phoneTxt.text.length < 10)
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Please enter a valid phone number" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
if(range.length + range.location > textField.text.length)
{
    return NO;
}

NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;

if(textField == ziptextField){
   return newLength <= 6;
 }
else if(textField == phonenukmbertextField){
   return newLength <= 10;
 }
 return YES;
```

Comment: This is what you needed...try this updated code and use it conditionally

Answer (score 2):

Your both Zip and Phone numbers are integer textfields, so why don't you change `keyboardtype` of **textfield** to `numberpad`. Then, in your `shouldChangeCharactersInRange`

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
 {

       NSString * currentStr = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

       if (textfield.tag == 10 && currentStr.length == 6) // Zip Textfield 
       {
          return false;
       }
       if (textfield.tag == 11 && currentStr.length == 10) // Phone Textfield 
       {
          return false;
       }
}
```